Does anyone know how to make torn fabric in geometry nodes?
Does anyone know how to make torn fabric in geometry nodes? Like this:


Hello and welcome to BSE. What have you tried?

I was trying something like that

How do you want to model this ? With curves ? With edges ? With faces ? Do you want to mesh it, or to prepare data in GN that are used after in a Shader ?

Hello and welcome juan,
The main idea is to distort the mesh with a Noise Texture and then bring the mesh back to the faces of the original object with a Geometry Proximity and a Set Position node:



I hope it helps.

@quellenform Thanks for the edit.

thank you very much it was what I was looking for! <3
